# Selecting items from one column based on values in another.

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
id1，id2
1    3
1    8
1    10
1    11
2    3
2    10
2    11
3    2
3    18
3    20
4    3
4    8
5    3
5    10
5    11
5    40
5    45
5    50
6    1
6    59
6    70
```

I won't get all id1 with id2 ＝ 3，10，11.

For example, id1=4 only with id2=3, should not return.

The results should be

```
id1
1
2
5
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be nice if you enter a question, not just a bunch of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL code

```
SELECT ID1,COUNT(ID2) FROM TBTEST 
WHERE ID2 IN(3,10,11) 
GROUP BY ID1 
HAVING COUNT(ID2)=3
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: The grouping is not necessary, because every occurence of ID2 = 3 occurs only one time per ID1.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct(ID1) FROM TBTEST WHERE ID2 IN(3,10,11)
```

Comment: Sorry. For example, id1=4 only with id2=3, should not return.